# Sobolev function in $X = W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{2,2}(\Omega) $

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega =\left(0,1 \right)$. Given a function $u \in X = W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{2,2}(\Omega)  $ I am looking for a function  $v \in X$, such that $$v'' =max(0,u'')$$.

Can one always find such a function ? I  am a little confused about this, would appreciate any help/hints.

Comment: What about setting $$v(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^t \max(0,u''(s))\, dsdt - x\int_0^1\int_0^t \max(0,u''(s))\, dsdt?$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $v$ as weak solution of $v''=\max(0,u'')$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Due to Sobolev regularity $v\in H^2(\Omega)$.